# randomly choose few lines from a file and then choose same line nos from second file

Tags: linux, shell, random, shuffle

I have 2 files, say A.txt and B.txt, each having 100 lines. I want to choose 10 records randomly from file A (which can easily be done with linux `shuf` command). But now I want same line nos data from file B also. Is there any easy way to do it via linux command line.

For Example: Following are the records from 2 files,
A1........A100
B1........B100

If 10 random records generated from A are A1, A3, A9, etc, then i want B1, B3, B9, etc from file B.

Answer (score 2):

This `bash` script will do this, to two files provided as args:

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do
  NR=$(($RANDOM % 100 + 1))
  echo -n "File $1, line $NR: "
  sed "$NR"'q;d' "$1"
  echo -n "File $2, line $NR: "
  sed "$NR"'q;d' "$2"
done
```

eg. usage:

`bash ./get10.sh long_file.txt longfile.txt`

Comment: It works pretty well. But for few records it gives following errors and fails:

sed: -e expression #1, char 2: invalid usage of line address 0

Any idea how to overcome it ???

Comment: Right, sed numerates lines from 1, not 0. So it should be `$(($RANDOM % 100 + 1))` there ( upated answer ).

Comment: RANDOM can return the same NR/line more than once. Te original shuf will give 10 different lines but OP asks for random records. Not really clear what is wanted.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to `paste` the two files together:

```
paste file_a file_b | shuf -n 10
```

To separate the two files, you could use awk:

```
paste file_a file_b | shuf -n 10 | awk '{ print $1 > "a_sample"; print $2 > "b_sample" }'
```

By default, paste joins the two files together with a tab character in between, which works with awk's default field separator. If the actual data in `file_a` and `file_b` contains spaces (but no tabs), you can set the input field separator to only tabs using `awk -F'\t'`.

Comment: It is really simple and easy to understand, thanks. Just a small correction, you need to add -F'\t'  with awk command, as paste generates tab delimited data.

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, the default input field separator is fine, as it works for any type of white space, so no need to change it unless the input files contain spaces too.